# How do i avoid duplicate items after adding product from database on listbox?

Tags: c#, asp.net, listbox

i've been trying to find solution but it doesnt seem to work. I'm trying to add a product from my Database Product then put it on Purchases database. On the other hand, when i press my product 1 Add to Cart button, it will appear in my Listbox. When the second time i press add to cart button, it will show a "Duplicate item " message. I tried a lot of codes but it keeps on adding and adding. This are my codes below. In the beginning, my listbox will be empty so when i press or my user press the Add To Cart button, it will appear in the listbox including the duplicate item feature. Hope to get some help. Will appreciate it a lot. Thanks!

```
 string uname = Convert.ToString(Session["username"]);
    int memberid = Convert.ToInt32(Session["memberID"]);
    SqlConnection connAdd1 = new SqlConnection("Server=localhost; Database = WeFootball; Integrated Security=SSPI");
    SqlCommand prod = new SqlCommand("Select * from purchases", connAdd1);
    connAdd1.Open();

    SqlDataReader dr;
    dr = prod.ExecuteReader();
    while (dr.Read())
    {
        ListItem meow = new ListItem(product1);
        if (cartlist.Items.Contains(meow))
        {

            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "alert", "alert('Duplicate item detected!');window.location ='Products.aspx';", true);
        }
        else
        {
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "alert", "alert('Added to cart!');window.location ='Products.aspx';", true);
        }
    }

    dr.Close();
    connAdd1.Close();


    if (cartlist.Items.Count == 0)
    {

        SqlConnection connAdd2 = new SqlConnection("Server=localhost; Database = WeFootball; Integrated Security=SSPI");
        //string uname = Convert.ToString(Session["username"]);
        //int memberid = Convert.ToInt32(Session["memberID"]);
        connAdd2.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = connAdd2.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.CommandText = "insert into purchases(member_name,product_name,quantity,purchase_by,product_id,member_id) values('" + uname + "','" + product1 + "','" + 1 + "','" + uname + "','" + 1 + "','" + memberid + "')";

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        connAdd2.Close();

        BindData();
    }
```

Comment: Where do you change the value of `product1` in `ListItem meow = new ListItem(product1);`? You probably need to read something from the `dr`.

Comment: @J.vanLangen can you help me out? I put a while(dr.read())

Comment: I don't know the structure of the database _(Select *)_, but you should extract the information out of the `dr["columnName"]` and convert it to the right type. On your comment, I looks like you don't know what you need to do. You should rephrase your question.